# Compositing: low quality scaling of Transform and Scale nodes

Tags: compositing-nodes, transforms

I want to use Compositing to get a second smaller image from a 3759x2800 pixel render. The second image must be 537x400 pixels. But the quality of the result is very low. I tried with both the Scale node and the Transform node (with Bicubic filter). This is the result with the Transform node:

[image]

As a comparison, this is the same image scaled from 3759x2800 pixels to 537x400 pixels in Photoshop:

[image]

I don't mean I'm looking for the exact same Photoshop result. But it seems impossible to me that the bicubic filter of the Transform node generates such a jagged image. Is it a bug?

These are the nodes used:
[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: Hi :). Adobe's scaling algorithms are a bit of a trade secret, since it's a lot more complicated topic. Related: [What is the best image downscaling algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384991)

Comment: just a dumb question: did you try to do a new render with just lower resolution? Or does that take too long?

Comment: @Chris you're right, what you propose is a solution. But the image I need at various sizes is already a composition of 3 renders (composed by the Compositing system). So doing it twice would mean doing 6 renders. And if I wanted other dimensions, how much render should I do?
What I would like to understand is why the Scale and Transform nodes do such a bad job. Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

Comment: @Michele: I don't know. I think Jachym is right - looks like scaling is a myth for itself....

Comment: all i can offer, i could try it out if you provide your blend file with your images...but i think you don't want that

Comment: @JachymMichal thank you MIchal. I don't mean I'm looking for the same Photoshop result. But it seems impossible to me that the bicubic filter of the Transform node generates such a jagged image. The Scale and Transform nodes are fundamental in a Compositing system. I can't believe that these Blender nodes do such a poor job, surpassed in quality by any image processor I know (out of curiosity, I also tested it with Microsoft Paint and it is closer to Photoshop than Blender ).

Comment: @Chris thank you very much for your kindness. Tomorrow I am in the office and I prepare the file to send it to you. I need to remove an item that is a customer confidential product, but the problem will show up anyway. How can I send you the file?

Comment: you can use https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions (but in the last few days this doesn't work) so if it doesn't work use any cloud service you want like google drive, dropbox...whatever. But please don't let us ask for permissions...you can delete everything in your blend file which isn't necessary for reproduction of the problem. So you have quicker uploads, we have quicker downloads ;)

Comment: Hi @Chris. I have prepared the file, you can download it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/t/Xw4vGtuWuNgz3lES
Compositing uses the Transform node to scale the high resolution image. The shrunken image is jagged with a worse quality than any even basic image processing software. A bicubic filter should do much better, I think there is something wrong.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Michele: thank you for providing your blend file. I could reproduce your problem. What computer are u using? If i scale down on my mac just in "preview" it got this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKf7L.png which is better than blender scaling...and this was a 10 sec render result...

Comment: @Chris: I use a Windows 10 workstation, and the "small" rendering is fast. In fact, to overcome the problem I am doing a lower resolution render. But for some projects I will have to generate various images of different resolutions, and I would like to understand if the problem is my error or a Blender bug. In the second case I would like to report the bug because having such a basic node that works badly is a problem in the use of Compositing. What do you think?

Comment: It’s worth a try. I also reported some bugs. Hopefully they improve it. But maybe the answer will be „works as designed“ 

Comment: @Chris:  Does the problem occur to you too? Isn't that my mistake?

Comment: What happens if you just scale it down on windows with „normal“ windows tools?

Comment: @Chris:  OK, if I have to generate many images at different sizes I will create an automated process with an external tool.
Thanks for your help, you were very kind.